# How to publish a GML file as a Web Feature Service (WFS)?

Tags: open-source, geoserver, gml-geographic-markup-lan

I am interested in publishing a GML file as a WFS. I don't want to use a database like PostgreSQL. What would be the rough steps I need to do for that? I like to use open source software (geoserver).

Answer (score 1):

The following steps are for publishing a SHP file as a WFS. I assume they are similiar for a GML file.

> The process for setting up a WFS in GeoServer requires the creation of
>   3 main components: a Workspace, Store, and Layer.  You can use
>   existing workspaces and stores to set up your layer but in this
>   tutorial we will be creating new ones.   A workspace is used as a
>   grouping of similar layers.  In this case we will call our workspace
>   “Vancouver”.   A store is used to make the connection to our
>   shapefile.  We will call our store “City Blocks”.   A layer is the
>   actual GIS data itself.  We will call our layer “blocks”.   The first
>   thing you need to do is download the sample data for Vancouver’s city
>   blocks.  Place the shapefile in your data directory. I have placed
>   mine in the data_dir/data/shapefiles directory that I set up when
>   installing GeoServer.  The data_dir is under the root of the GeoServer
>   installation.   Sign into GeoServer and click the “Create workspaces”
>   link.
>
> Under Name, enter “Vancouver”.  Under Namespace URI, enter something
>   that relates to your project.  This is typically a URL.  For this
>   example I have used “blocks”. Click Submit.   GeoServer New Workspace 
>   Go back to the GeoServer administrator home by clicking its logo. 
>   This time click the “Add stores” button.  Under “Vector Data Sources”
>   choose “Shapefile”.
>
> Under Workspace, choose “Vancouver”.  For the Data Source Name, enter
>   “City Blocks”.
>
> Under URL, you must enter the absolute path to your shapefile, or the
>   relative path from your data directory.  In this case we will enter a
>   relative path “file:data/shapefiles/blocks.shp”.  Click Save.
>   GeoServer New Vector Data Source   You will be taken to the new layer
>   chooser.  Click Publish for your blocks layer.   Under Coordinate
>   Reference Systems > Native SRS, you will see that it is UNKNOWN. But
>   we know that our data is NAD83 UTM Zone 10 North.  We will specify
>   this under “Declared SRS”.  Enter “EPSG: 26910”.
>
> You should notice GeoServer recognizes this as “EPSG:NAD83 / UTM zone
>   10N...”.   Under Bounding Boxes >Native Bounding Box, click the
>   “Compute from data” link.
>
> Under Lat/Lon Bounding Box, click the “Compute from native bounds”
>   link and click Save.   GeoServer Publish Layer   Your shapefile is now
>   set up for use as a WFS. To preview your layer, click on “Layer
>   Preview” in the GeoServer menu, find the “Vancouver:blocks” layer and
>   select your desired format.   The user is now able to serve shapefiles
>   as Web Feature Services through GeoServer.

This is based on the following tutorial:
http://www.gistutor.com/geoserver/11-beginner-geoserver-tutorials/36-setting-up-a-wfs-in-geoserver-using-a-shapefile.html